# How to Join multiple rectangles using html5 and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I created multiple rectangles using Canvas with unique id for each rectangle

```
<table class="trpnl" id="tblPanel" style="width:300%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr style="height:40px;"></tr>
@for(var i=1;i<=15;i++)
{
  <tr>
  <td style="width:20px;"></td>
  <td>                                  
  <canvas id="newCanvas_@i" width="200" height="8" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>                                               
  </td>
  </tr>
} 
</table>
```

this is JavaScript code for canvas

```
 for(var i=1;i<=15;i++)
  {
    var c = document.getElementById('newCanvas'+"_"+i)
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#708090';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 10);
  }
```

Here I am getting output like this
[image: Here I am getting output like this]

I want to show output like this
[image: But I want to show the output like this]

I tried cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" to the table but nothing works
can anyone please give me an idea how to merge or join those rectangles like expected output.
TIA.

Comment: Why do you think you need a <canvas> here?

Comment: Please include the actual output as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: Also note that table attributes were left in the past in favour of CSS for almost everything: you're looking for [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) but as @Kaiido asks: why are you using canvas elements here at all? They're just rectangles, and the table cells themselves are literally rectangles, so... just set their background color and then use black as table background? =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it both "actions" in the same loop.

```js
const panel = document.querySelector('.panel'),
      rows = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (let i=1; i<=15; i++) {
  const c = document.createElement('CANVAS');
  c.width = 200;
  c.height = 10;
  const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = '#708090';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  rows.appendChild(c);
}

panel.appendChild(rows);
```

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}
.panel canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel"></div>
```